# is it possible to send a byte array in a JMS message

Tags: java, jms

is it possible to send a byte array in a JMS message ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

From [IBM support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/transcode_byte_array_to_msg_payload.html)

> A mediation can transcode a byte array into a message payload without changing the meaning of the message.

From [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/jms/BytesMessage.html)

> Although the JMS API allows the use of message properties with byte messages, they are typically not used, since the inclusion of properties may affect the format.
>
> The primitive types can be written explicitly using methods for each type. They may also be written generically as objects. For instance, a call to BytesMessage.writeInt(6) is equivalent to BytesMessage.writeObject(new Integer(6)). Both forms are provided, because the explicit form is convenient for static programming, and the object form is needed when types are not known at compile time.